# A security vulnerability has been detected in your application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sprockets

I'm running a Rails on Heroku over a year but today i'm facing a issue which not push fails to Heroku latest commit, when I run `git push heroku master` then like below

````
remote:  !     A security vulnerability has been detected in your application.
remote:  !     To protect your application you must take action. Your application
remote:  !     is currently exposing its credentials via an easy to exploit directory
remote:  !     traversal.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To protect your application you must either upgrade to Sprockets version "3.7.2"
remote:  !     or disable dynamic compilation at runtime by setting:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     ```
remote:  !     config.assets.compile = true # Disables security vulnerability
remote:  !     ```
remote:  !     
remote:  !     To read more about this security vulnerability please refer to this blog post:
remote:  !     https://blog.heroku.com/rails-asset-pipeline-vulnerability
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to project-us.
````

I have tried to `true` in `assets.compile` but nothing changed.

What can I do now?

Comment: It's saying to read there blog article https://blog.heroku.com/rails-asset-pipeline-vulnerability why you can't read this, I think you can find a solution to reading this article, How to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what *precisely* you don't understand about that message and the linked blog post? That way, the Heroku developers can improve the wording so that other users don't stumble over the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bundle update sprockets
git commit -am "update sprockets"
git push heroku master
```